# App publishing in App store from another account

Tags: ios, app-store

My App is already published on App store but my client gets a conflict with the publisher party. Now an updated application is in pending state for which my worried client suggested me if we can upload this application from new developers account as many of customers aren't comfort to using the app with bugs.

Now, I want to published it from my account. what should I do ?

Any suggestions ?

p.s That party has no more contact with us now and they are not even removing our app from thier developers account.

Answer (score 1):

Here few things you can do :

- That application is of your client & they have all the rights of the concept & idea & name of the application. So in that case you can send an appeal to the apple support team
- If they will feel it appropriate then apple review team will immediately take an action & that application will be removed from that account

Now the question is how you can publish the same app from another account. So for that :

- First thing is app name is already in use now so it won't allow you to take a same name even if app removed from sale.
- So best thing you can do is you can modify slightly app name & than reuse it for submitting app again

**Important Note :**

- For resubmitting the app you should have a latest source first. If you already have it than there will be no issues for you in resubmitting app on new iTunes account.
- But don't forget to send appeal to the support team for the app is already live on the store by mis using your client details & wait till apple team takes actions against that app

Hope it will helps.

Comment: How to generate complain in apple for it? Does it creates an issue when resubmitting?